# Choosing the correct transformer for the dual rail Welleman regulator kit 8042

Tags: power-supply, transformer

I have this dual power supply 1 A kit by Welleman

[image]

with this schematic:

[image: http://www.waynekirkwood.com/images/jpg/Velleman_K8042_Schematic.jpg]

My problem is understanding what transformer I could apply. If you have seen schematic, I must select a transformer with two windings on the secondary but the question is:

How could I evaluate voltage and current which exiting from secondary winding of transformer? In general what calculations which I have to apply to dimension voltage and current coming out from the secondary of a transformer in order to select right transformer for projecting my custom power supply?

Comment: What does the datasheet tell you about the maximum and dropout voltages of the LM317?

Comment: What is the maximum current and voltage that you need from the PSU?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is a pretty good choice is the value of voltage you want at the output. So in this case a 12-0-12 or 15-0-15 secondary. It might also be labeled '24V CT' (for 24 volts center-tapped) or 30 V CT respectively.

The peak voltage produced by the transformer is above the nominal value by a factor of 1.4. You can look up 'RMS' if you want to understand this better. So a 12 V secondary will actually produce almost 17 V peak. That's good, because a few volts are dropped across the rectifier diodes and the so-called "drop-out" voltage of the linear regulator (LM317/LM337 in this case).

The "voltage you want at the output" isn't a good rule for the general case, it just happens to work out fairly well at 12-15 V. If you were looking for 5 V or 30 V out you'd want to take a sharper pencil to it.

Line transformers come in two varieties that will work here. One is a "dual secondary" and the other is "center-tapped". A dual secondary has two completely separate secondary windings, meaning four separate wiring connections there. A center-tapped will usually only have three. Either will work in this case since there is just the one "0V" connection to the transformer.

Comment: Ok, I can use both kinds of transformes, but about current, the kit manual reports 1A current output so how I could evaluate transformer in function of current output?
Is useful finding output current from transformer for evaluating output current of power supply and, in case of affermative answer, in what way this must be calculated?

Comment: The current out of the supply will be the same as the current through the transformer secondary. So you want the secondary to be rated for that current. Typically this is stated, as [here](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/177/186-187-948805.pdf). If only the VA (volt-amps) rating is given, you simply divide by the output voltage to get the amps, but best to be conservative in that case, and also be sure to use the *entire* voltage (e.g. 24 or 30) in the calculations. So for 2 x 12V @ 1A, you probably want a 30VA transformer.

Comment: About fuse, what value must have fuse for protection of supply?
Is it right use a 10A fuse for single phase or no?

Comment: @NicolaBombonati: 10A is *far* too large, especially if on the primary of the transformer. Figure out what the maximum current draw will be and add 30%.

Comment: @NicolaBombonati: On the primary, the VA are the same, but the voltage is much higher, so the amperage is much lower. So for a 24 VA transformer, the maximum input current would be around 24 VA / 120 V = 0.2 A. So you should be thinking about a fuse in the 250 - 500 milliamp (mA) range, depending on the transformer you select.

Comment: This is the transformer which I would want apply to kit:

http://it.aliexpress.com/item/AC-15V-30VA-Output-Open-Frame-EI-Core-Power-Transformer-Electronic-Components/1893069242.html?spm=2114.46010308.4.93.IVPmxr

Comment: @NicolaBombonati: On reading a bit more on this, I think you'll want a 40 VA transformer if you intend to pull 1 A out of both sides at the same time. The rectifier and smoothing capacitor will operate at 1.414 times the nominal voltage, so 21 V for a 15 V transformer. A 1 A load would come to 42 VA. The transformer you linked to has the right description (excepting only 30 VA capacity), but the picture shows not enough wires on the secondary. There should be 4 secondary wires by the description. So you might want to send a message to the seller.

Comment: @NicolaBombonati Remember to use a slow-blow fuse in the live wire on the mains side because a transformer can have quite a large in-rush current when you switch it on. (It will draw lots of current to charge the smoothing capacitors.)